# Python Floating Point Rounding

Tags: python, rounding, python-3.4

Trying to figure out the correct rounding technique:

```
v = float(input("Enter V: "))

print ("V is %.3f" % str(round(v,3)))
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have a missing close-paren/bracket on your first line.

Comment: On your second line you shouldn't be casting to a string. Also the format specifier you have handles the display to 3 digits after the decimal point so the call to `round()` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yeah this is not my actual program I was just giving an example. I see i missed a closing bracket, but I got it working as I want now.

Comment: Edited and fixed the missing bracket since it's not the subject of the question and it shouldn't stir the conversation about the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
str(round(v,3)
```

is the problem here, just remove the `str`

you're changing into a string, which is wrong

Answer (score -1):

Using `str` turns the float into a string. Remove the `str`:

```
print ("V is %.3f" % round(v, 3))
```

**UPDATE**
As Barnie suggested in a comment above: there's no need for rounding since you're printing using `%.3f` so you do even better:

```
print ("V is %.3f" % v)
```